Coefficient of derivatives on power function
Consider a product of functions, each raised to some power:
$$
\prod_i f_i(x)^{z_i}
$$
If I take $m$ derivatives with respect to $x$, I will end up with a sum of terms that looks like the following:
$$
\left(\sum_{n=1}^m\ \sum_{\{i_k\}_{k=1}^n} \ c_{\{i_k\}}\prod_{k=1}^n z_{i_k}\frac{\partial^{r_k} \log f_{i_k}}{\partial x^{r_k}} \right)\prod_i f_i(x)^{z_i},\ \text{such that}\, \sum_k r_k = m
$$
I want to know if there is a combinatorial argument that would allow me to derive an expression for the value of the coefficient for each index set $c_{\{i_k\}}$ in front of the product of derivatives. Thanks for the help.
